# Visual Studio code rails unable to see end of function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I am using visual code for my rails development I am using ruby extension. I am trying to see the end of my code section For example when I am putting cursor on my angular code I can see what is the end of that code. Example in this image:

[image]

As you can see in this image when I put my cursor and  I can see where is ending. But in my ruby code when I put my cursor at def I don't see end highlighter I don't know what is the solution for this.

Is there any extension available which can help me see the end of all my codes or block. For Rails applications.

Is there any plugin available like: https://atom.io/packages/ruby-block  this in visual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this extension on my VS code and it works perfectly along with showing the end of all codes and blocks.

https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby

[image]

Hope this helps out, though for development I prefer Ruby Mine.

Comment: What version of VS Code are you using ? can you share your example code for which it doesn't work ? will check with that code.